# How can I replace dataframe elements with their column average?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am looking for a function like the following:

```
new_df = df.fill(df.mean(), axis=1)
```

Example:

```
  6   3
  4   5
```

to:

```
  5  4
  5  4
```

Comment: What do you mean? A column whose item is the average of all the elements in the same row? Can you provie an input and the expected output?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco I added an example

Comment: Why do you need such dataframe? Do you simply need to subtract it from the original one?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco No, just I want the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is:

```
new_df = df.add(df.mean()-df, axis=1)

#new_df
#    0     1
#0   5.0   4.0
#1   5.0   4.0
```

Comment: I asked you in the comments substraction was an option... This is exactly what I meant! next time be more specific please.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco did I substract or add something? the output is just the output of your solution but with a shorter solution! What's the difference? I just said I need the output in any possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply numpy's `mean` function and broadcast the result:

```
import numpy as np
df.apply(np.mean, result_type='broadcast')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[6, 3], [4, 5]])
result = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(pd.DataFrame([df.mean()]).values, len(df), axis=0))
```

Comment: I myself found a simpler solution added as an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
# your input df
df = pd.DataFrame([[6, 3], [4, 5]], columns = ['col1', 'col2'])

# to get output df as you want
for col in df.columns: df[col] = df[col].mean()

#df
#   col1  col2
#0   5.0   4.0
#1   5.0   4.0
```

Comment: thanks, I myself found a simpler solution added as an answer